# Magento 2 Elastic search 6 Fulltext search with like

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento-search

I am trying to customize the default Magento 2 Elasticsearch 6. Right now the default Fulltext search is not giving that good result.

For Example I have product name like `ADB12355 BBB`, `ADB3456 AAA`, etc.

I am getting proper results either when adding `ADB12355 BBB` or `ADB3456`. The problem is I also want both the products if someone just search for `ADB` some kind of `LIKE` in mysql.

Also My configuration is correct and indexes are created but So far I am not able to find the correct place to customize.

Comment: go to marketing -> seo and search -> search synonyms, there you can add synonyms for the adb search that will include the product names returned by search. Also ensure the name attribute is enabled for search.

Answer (score 3):

Give a try.

Add plugin on the below class `Builder.php` by making a sample module.

**File: app/code/Custom/LikeSearch/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder">
        <plugin name="custom_like_search_builder" type="Custom\LikeSearch\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index\CustomBuilder"></plugin>
</type>
```

**File: Custom\LikeSearch\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index\CustomBuilder.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\LikeSearch\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index;

class CustomBuilder {

    public function afterBuild(\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder $subject, $result)
    {
        $likeToken = $this->getLikeTokenizer();
        $result['analysis']['tokenizer'] = $likeToken;
        $result['analysis']['filter']['trigrams_filter'] = [
            'type' => 'ngram',
            'min_gram' => 3,
            'max_gram' => 3
        ];
        $result['analysis']['analyzer']['my_analyzer'] = [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
            'filter' => [
                'lowercase', 'trigrams_filter'
            ]
        ];
        return $result;
    }


    protected function getLikeTokenizer()
    {
        $tokenizer = [
            'default_tokenizer' => [
                'type' => 'ngram'
            ],
        ];
        return $tokenizer;
    }
}
```

Once done perform the `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

It should give results like below:

For search term, `ADB` gives results of below products names

**ADB12355 BBB**

**ADB3456 AAA**

For search term, `GIT` gives results of below products names

**ABCGIT AAA**

**XYZGIT BBB**

Comment: I can confirm changing the ngram min/max values to 3 greatly improves this sort of search. You can also consider increasing  the search weight of the sku attribute to improve sku searches. Great answer @sandip !

Comment: I used this but getting all the products in search result even if I am searching any random string "shsskjkxnxs" which doesn't even exist. Please help me to achieve this. @paj

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this issue, it provides some more information https://blog.gaiterjones.com/how-to-improve-magento-2-elasticsearch-catalog-search-results-and-relevance/

Comment: Thanks @paj!! Great Help.

Comment: I was looking to create my first custom Elasticsearch module and tried this code into  custom module but it's not working...also ran s:d:c, c:f, indexing etc but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this isn't a direct answer to the question however I'd recommend using https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite. It's open source, very customisable, and has some excellent features included such as autocomplete and search optimisers.

Comment: As A LOT of other users, "No alive nodes found in your cluster"

Answer (score 0):

you have to set AND operator in your elastic search json queries, Override the module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php. file in your custom module and then The code you have to edit in the build function in line no 75

```
if($matchKey != 'match_phrase_prefix'){$matchQuery['operator'] = "AND";}
```

Also make sure you are not setting the operator in match_phrase_prefix.

After this you'll get exact matches in catalog search.

This has been tested well for magento CC 2.4.0

Comment: This is not working with M2.4.2 any suggestion?