# Magento 2 - How to increase % match of search term?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I want to increase the percentage (%) match of search term so that the most relevant matching product will show on top. From where should I do that? I tried finding it in Smile Elastic Suite setting but didn't get it.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307365/34579 - check this answer. this will surely help.

Comment: Is this valid for smile elastic suite?  Because it's saying that class \Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder not found

Comment: This is for only Magento default elastic only.

Comment: If smile suite module depends on the Magento elastic search then it should work.

Comment: I have deployed your changes but its not working

Comment: yes The above link changes won't work in your case. Check my answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to the question.

1. Read this reply it may help you in some way.

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1655#issuecomment-571137468

2. Try below by overriding the XML files into the one of website custom module

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1536#issuecomment-579817912

3. For detailed information on Smile-Suite

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki