# Magento 2.3.3 not finding substrings?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I am having problems using the search in my Magento 2.3.3. shop. When I search for "diffusor", it finds products. Searching for "usor" on the other side, finds nothing. The search term is either contained in the name or in the description.

Any idea why this is not working and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch or MySQL as the catalog search engine?

Comment: Tried both, same result

Comment: @EOB try this ready-made plugin working example - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307365/34579  you will surely get the results.