# M 2.4.2 - catalog Search with custom attribute not showing

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.4.2, catalogsearch-fulltext

I am using Magento 2.4.2, but sometimes the default search bar does not work elasticsearch engine for the catalog search.

For example, I have a product with custom attribute  called "**HU816x56**". When I search "**HU816**", it does not display the result.

Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307365/34579  - Try to implement this